# How I can insert data with react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to insert data into a SQL Server database with nodejs API but I cannot send data from react-native. Data is not come to web API I tried `axios.post` and fetch method, I couldn't do this. What am I doing wrong? Could you help me?

This is my NODE JS WEB API:

```
app.post("/insert", function(req, res) {          
    (async function insert(ProName,ProDesc,OnDate) {    
    try {                   
          let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
          const request= pool.request();   
          request.input("ProName", sql.VarChar, ProName)
          request.input("ProDesc", sql.VarChar, ProDesc)
          request.input("OnDate", sql.VarChar, OnDate)   
          request.query('INSERT INTO Producttbl 
    (ProName,ProDesc,OnDate) VALUES(@ProName,@ProDesc,@OnDate)',
```

React native code:

```
          state = {ProName:'',ProDesc:'',OnDate:''};        
          insert= () =>{
        const {ProName,ProDesc,OnDate}=this.state;
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'url/insert',
          data: {
           ProName,
            ProDesc,
            OnDate
      },      
      }).then(response =>        

      this.setState({
        ProName:response.ProName,
        ProDesc:response.ProDesc,
        OnDate:response.OnDate
      });
      })

 <TextInput  onChangeText={(ProName)=>this.setState({ProName})} />
```

JSON:

```
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEwn2.png
```

Comment: Is there any error on your console ? how and when do you call your insert() ?

Comment: Yes, Network error and node js WEB API : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjX7s.png

Comment: The problem might be on your NodeJS, not on your React Native, try to resolve that error first